# Prove that, for all ordered sets P, Q and R,

Tags: order-theory

$\langle P \rightarrow \langle Q \rightarrow R\rangle \rangle  \cong \langle P \times Q \rightarrow R\rangle $

where $\langle Q \rightarrow R\rangle $ is the set of all order-preserving maps from Q to P; $\cong$ is order-isomorphic symbol; $\times$ is cartesian product symbol.

Besides I am not good at building bijection to prove isomorphism, I hope you can teach me some technique on this issue.

Comment: You should specify the order on each set.

Comment: no, i don't think so. It is a question from "Introduction to lattices and order" B. A. Davey and H. A. Priestley, exercise 1.26, 2nd edition

Comment: Please write `\langle…\rangle` to get $\langle…\rangle$. Typing `<…>` produces relation symbols, which not only look different, but also produce different spacing.

Comment: @raycaesar I know, it's exercise 1.24 if I recall correctly. But the question would be more complete if you specified how $P\times Q$ and $\langle P\to Q\rangle$ are ordered.

Comment: OK, thanks for your mention. I will henceforth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\varphi\in\langle P\to\langle Q\to R\rangle\rangle$; then for each $p\in P$, $\varphi(p)$ is an order-preserving map from $Q$ to $R$. Define

$$\widehat\varphi:P\times Q\to R:\langle p,q\rangle\mapsto\big(\varphi(p)\big)(q)\;.$$

Show that the map $\varphi\mapsto\widehat\varphi$ is the desired isomorphism.